# debezium connector failover mechanism

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, debezium-engine

i'm learning about debezium connectors and im using debezium for postgresql. I have a small question to clarify.

Imagine a situation like this. I have a debezium connector for a table called tableA and changes happening on that table publish to a topic called topicA. Connector works without any issue and changes are publishing to the topic without any issue. Now think that for some reason i need to delete my connector and start a new connector with the same configurations for the same table that publish to the same topic. So there is a time gap between i stop my connector and start a new one with same configs. What happen to the data that get change during that time on my tableA.

Will that gonna start from where it stopped or what will happen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dushan , The answer is depends on how the connector stops. The various scenarios are articulated here

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-kafka-connect-process-stops-gracefully

In an ideal case scenario , the Log Sequence Number is recorded in the database history topic. Unless the history topic is re-created or messages expired the LSN offsets are stored and on restart will resume from that location

Comment: yes, in my scenario, i deleted the connector manually. So what i found out was this.

if the name of the new connector will be same as previous one, it will start where previous one stopped. The position where it stopped is stored in the Kafka topic, so the new one just resumes (unless you clean up corresponding kafka topic).

Comment: but if you are using msk, it default uses fresh offset storage topic so the offsets are not kept between recreated connectors. 

For anyone interested - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-connect-workers.html#msk-connect-manage-connector-offsets